# ASP.Net MVC Routes not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

We have several routes in our Global.asax.cs file, but one of them is not apparently being used.

```
// Search (NOT working).
routes.MapRoute(
         "Search",
         "search/{query}",
         new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" });

// Homepage (I believe the problem could be here, but not sure).
routes.MapRoute(
         "MainIndex",
         "{language}",
         new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", language = string.Empty });
```

When we do a search in the search form which action attribute is "/Search", the user is sent to the homepage and the URL in the address bar is "/Search?query=example+search".

The form action attribute is built in using this code:

```
<form id="form1" action="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Search") %>">
```

Seems right to me, but the action name should be "/search" instead of "/Search", right?

Comment: I assume the Search route is listed *before* the MainIndex route in your code (just like you have it in your post), correct?

Comment: Yes, Hector. The search route is listed __before__ the MainIndex route.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried your route with the following view

```
<form id="form1"  method="post" action="<%= Url.Action("Index", "Search") %>">
Enter something: <input type="text" name="query" id="query" value="hello" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and a controller like this

```
public ActionResult Index(string query)
{
    return View();
}
```

and it works OK. Notice that (1) I am using method=post and (2) that the textbox has both a name and ID set to "query" which is what the Html.TextBox would have done for you. This is what allowed the binding to pick up the value and pass it correctly to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

I always find this tool extremely helpful in debugging routes. [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `"search/{query}"` match the case => `"Search/{query}"`

Well your action on the form tag is `/Search/Index`, which will match your `Search/{query}` route, but your query will be Index. However, with the `?query=example+search` on the end of your route, the Search route won't know how to handle that query parameter. I would just update the action attribute on the form tag to just be `/Search` and not use the URL helper.

Comment: No, that wasn't the cause of the error since the route was well made. Only the route search was not caught while making the action attribute of the form, because the route demanded the query parameter which did not exist before the form was submitted ("/search" did not correspond to the route "search/{query}"). But thanks! Good try +1